# How do I implement modal images in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I am making an image gallery with a sorter that uses Bootstrap modal images. I followed the modal documentation, however instead of a button I am using an image

I have recopied the modal form from the documentation and replaced it when needed. I have tested it on several browsers and they all do not work.

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column abstract">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" style="width:100%" data-toggle="modal" data-target"#abstractModalOne">
            <div class="modal fade" id="abstractModalOne" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="abstractModalOneLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="img">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="abstractModalOneLabel">Sea Lions</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

After clicking on the small image, it should open a bigger image in the same tab.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Not sure my answer is perfect for you but it's really help you for understand logic.

here is Modal HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 1" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-1" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/ccc/969696&amp;text=0xD10x810xD00xB50xD10x800xD10x8B0xD00xB9">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 2" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-2" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/2255EE/969696&amp;text=0xD10x810xD00xB80xD00xBD0xD00xB80xD00xB9">
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 3" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-3" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/449955/FFF&amp;text=0xD00xB70xD00xB50xD00xBB0xD00xB50xD00xBD0xD10x8B0xD00xB9">
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

  </div>
</div>

    <div class="hidden" id="img-repo">

        <!-- #image-1 -->
        <div class="item" id="image-1">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 11" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/ccc/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-1">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 12" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/ccc/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-1">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 13" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/969696">
        </div>

        <!-- #image-2 -->
        <div class="item" id="image-2">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 21" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/2255EE/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-2">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 21" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/2255EE/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-2">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 23" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/2255EE/969696">
        </div>   

        <!-- #image-3-->
        <div class="item" id="image-3">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 31" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/449955/FFF">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-3">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 32" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/449955/FFF">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-3">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 33" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/449955/FFF">
        </div>        

    </div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel">

            <div class="carousel-inner">           
            </div>

            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modal CSS

```
.thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}

.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
  background-image:none;
  margin-top:10%;
  width:5%;
}
```

Modal Js :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   /* activate the carousel */
   $("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

   /* change modal title when slide changes */
   $("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel",       function () {
        $(".modal-title")
        .html($(this)
        .find(".active img")
        .attr("title"));
   });

   /* when clicking a thumbnail */
   $(".row .thumbnail").click(function(){
    var content = $(".carousel-inner");
    var title = $(".modal-title");

    content.empty();  
    title.empty();

    var id = this.id;  
     var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
     var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
     var active = repoCopy.first();

    active.addClass("active");
    title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
    content.append(repoCopy);

    // show the modal
    $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
  });

});
```

For Example and reference code is [here](https://codepen.io/webcane/pen/lHGJf)

I hope it's help you..

Comment: Is there a way of implementing this without the carousel? And I see the example you linked is for bootstrap 3, while I am using bootstrap 4.

Comment: see this w3 School modal example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp may be it's help you. @sadrobotman